# Установчий чи установний чи установочний файл?

Tags: переклад, терміни, прикметники, суфікси

Як українською краще перекласти "Installation file"?

- **Установочний** — звучить як калька з російської
- **Установчий** — наче правильно, але не впевнений. "установчий файл -и" 146 000 результатів у Google
- **Установний** — теж наче може бути. "установний файл -и" 8 350 результатів у Google

Comment: Так розумію, цїкавить переклад саме з прикметником, бо якщо нї, то завжди є _файл встановки_.

Comment: Ще є банальний варіант [інсталяційний](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=інсталяційн*&dicts=all&highlight=on). (Звісно, краще використати слово з українським коренем, але я поки сам не знаю, який конкретно з цих трьох варіантів це має бути.)

Comment: @Sasha будь ласка, уникайте надавати (напів-)відповіді у коментарях. Коментарі існують **винятково** з метою уточнення/покращення допису, під яким їх надано. Наприклад, мені з внутрішніх документів щодо локалізації програмних продуктів великих корпорацій достеменно відомо, що правильна відповідь — *встановлювальний/встановлюваний/встановний*, що відтворює, відповідно, інструментальний, пасивний та активний аспекти. Але я не маю можливості надавати обґрунтування, і саме тому не пишу своєї необґрунтованої напів-відповіді через коментар.

Comment: Дякую за "необґрунтовані коментарі" ! Дійсно, можна і _файл установки_, не подумав про це. Замітив що трохи погано шукав — додав лапки до пошуку для точного збігу. `-и` щоб відсікти рос. видачу. Тепер:

`"файл установки" -и` - 241 тис.
`"установочний файл" -и` - 20 тис.
`"установчий файл" -и` - 8 тис.
`"інсталяційний файл" -и` - 6 тис.
`"установний файл" -и` - ~0.

Тож схоже що _файл установки_ використовується найбільше, далі _установочний файл_ — варіант який мені не дуже до вподоби, _установчий файл_ — на 3 місці, але як на мене непогано, можна також використовувати.

Comment: @LevLukomsky Re: `-и`: для Google ще допомагає `&lr=-(lang_ru)` в рядку URL (або `?lr=-(lang_ru)`, якщо параметр є першим).

Comment: Дужки необов'язково, достатньо просто `lr=-lang_ru`, наприклад [`https://google.com/search?q=тест&lr=-lang_ru`](https://google.com/search?q=тест&lr=-lang_ru).

Comment: коли шукаю з `&lr=-lang_ru` ґуґл не показує кількість знайдених результатів - це головне що мене цікавило.

Comment: Чи могли б ви навести контекст? Без нього я б перекладав, як "дистрибутив".